# Using emulator Firebase storage ref always returns null

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, firebase-tools

I am using Firebase Storage emulator and when I try to get a ref of a file I always get NULL and the code doesn't execute the remaining lines at the Future block.

```
class _ShowAVState extends State<ShowAV> {
  String downloadURL = '';
  Future<void> downloadURLExample() async {
    print('entrou no future');
    var firebaseStorageRef =
        // firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('teste.txt');
        firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('/teste.txt');
    print('CRIOU A REF');
    print(firebaseStorageRef);
    downloadURL = await firebaseStorageRef.getDownloadURL();
    // String downloadURL = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
    //     // .ref("/default-bucket/img/deliveryServicosAV.jpg")
    //     .ref()
    //     .child('deliveryServicosAV.jpg')
    //     .getDownloadURL();
    print('LINK: $downloadURL');
  }
```

Comment: first of all, confirm if you have google services in the emulator.

Comment: Hi. Do you mean Google API? Yes! I make calls to Gmail, Google Calendar and everything works fine. Also the others emulators (Firestore and Functions) work fine. Thanks for your attention.